# CSS image url in an npm package

Tags: css, webpack, relative-url, npm-package

I have a package that I am using in my main webpack-built app. In the package, I have a component with its corresponding `.scss` file. The folder structure is:

```
component
   |- assets
       |- background-image.svg
   component.tsx
   component.scss
```

`component.scss` is trying to use `background-image` as such:

`background: url('assets/bacgkround-image.svg')`

This works fine in a storybook file and the background is loaded properly.

However, when I try to include the component in my main React app, the build fails with the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/background-image.svg' in '<path-to-my-package-directory'
```

I am confused. What is the right way to include the image from a relative url in a css file?